# Angular auxiliary routes with named router-outlets: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment

Tags: angular, routes, angular7, router-outlet

I am having a hard time getting auxiliary routes to work, even in a minimalistic scenario.
I'm pretty sure, I stuck to the [angular documentation on routes and multiple outlets](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes#multiple-outlets) down to a T, so I really have no idea what I am missing.

**app.routing.ts**:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      // aux route with named outlet, **DOES NTO WORK :(**
      {
        path: 'simple',
        component: SimpleComponent,
        outlet: 'simpleOutlet'
      },

      // default route, *WORKS*
      {
        path: '',
        component: AppComponent
      },
      // fallback route, *WORKS*
      {
        path: '**',
        component: AppComponent,
        redirectTo: ''
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**app.component.html**:

```
<h2>I am the app component</h2>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="simpleOutlet"></router-outlet>
```

Before using `routerLink`, I wanted to get it to work by entering a URL right into the browser. Is it possible, that I missed something crucial regarding navigating to aux routes by direct URL?
Here's what happens when directly hacking in URLS:

- `http://localhost:4200/` works; `app.component.html` is displayed
- `http://localhost:4200/somethingfallback123` works; due to the fallback-route, `app.component.html` is displayed
- `http://localhost:4200/(simpleOutlet:simple)` **does not** work
  neither does `http://localhost:4200(simpleOutlet:simple)`, `http://localhost:4200/(simpleOutlet:/simple)`, `http://localhost:4200/(simpleOutlet:simple/)` etc.. (you can see, I am desperate)

---

**[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nlbhd3?embed=1&file=src/app/app.routing.ts)**

---

**ERROR LOGS:**

Mozilla Firefox:

```
ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
resolvePromise http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7882:31
resolvePromise http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7839:17
scheduleResolveOrReject http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7941:17
invokeTask http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7489:17
onInvokeTask http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:70021:24
invokeTask http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7488:17
runTask http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7256:28
drainMicroTaskQueue http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7663:25
```

It seems to be a know issue that Firefox does not throw correct error messages.

Google Chrome:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL             Segment: 'simple'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'simple'
```

---

**Environment (angular version: ng v)**

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.4
Node: 9.7.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.0.2
```

Comment: it will be easy to help you if you put your relevant code here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6s9716 (fork and post the link)

Comment: thank you for your response! I updated the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here the code to solve this issue [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b1hzcv?file=src/app/app.routing.ts)

in `app.routing.ts`

*instead*

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      // aux route with named outlet, **DOES NTO WORK :(**
      {
        path: 'simple',
        component: SimpleComponent
      },

      // default route, *WORKS*
      {
        path: '',
        component: AppComponent
      },
      // fallback route, *WORKS*
      {
        path: '**',
        component: AppComponent,
        redirectTo: ''
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

*do*

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
      // aux route with named outlet, **DOES NTO WORK :(**
      {
        path: 'simple',
        component: SimpleComponent,
        outlet: 'simpleOutlet'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

and *instead*

```
exports: [RouterModule, appRoutes]
```

*do*

```
exports: [RouterModule]
```

in `app.component.html`

*instead*

```
<h1>
  app component
</h1>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

*do*

```
<h1>
  app component
</h1>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="simpleOutlet"></router-outlet>
```

in `app.module.ts`

remove `import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';` you not need it here you already made a separated *Routing* file

*add*

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { SimpleComponent } from './simple/simple.component';
```

*instead*

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

*do*

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, SimpleComponent ],
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

do that as following `declarations` then `imports` the order is important as long you made a separated *routing* file

for more details and reference take a look on the link mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you so much!
For this minimalistic example, it finally works =)
I'm still having trouble with my actual project where I want to use this concept. Because I use seperate routing config files and resolver services there but I'm surre I will figure it out.

Unfortunately, I cannot give you positive ratings yet. But imagine, I gave you 200, which is about how many hours I've been stuck on this now.

Answer (score -1):

Change [`RouterModule`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule) to `RouterModule.forRoot([])` in app.module file:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, 
                  FormsModule, 
                  RouterModule.forRoot([]) //this line
                ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Comment: Thank you! But I don't  undestand what exactly you advise me to do.
Isn't there an argument missing in the `forRoot()` call as you wrote? For example `forRoot([appRoutes])` (with `appRoutes` being imported from `app.routing.ts` ?

Comment: remove the `forRoot([appRoutes])` from route as in this example:https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

Comment: If you pass an empty array to RouterModule.forRoot(), you're basically passing an empty list containing no routes, leading to nothing displaying at all...